# MySQL Command Line Client closing after entering password without any error

Tags: mysql

I'm using Windows Server 2016. I need MySQL for my school project. Now I've installed it and want to create a new database for Wordpress. The Problem that I have is, that when I enter my password in the Command Line Client the Client closes without any Error message. When opening the client, I get the Message: "mysql: [Warning] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysql.exe: ignoring option '--no-beep' due to invalid value ''." I also tried to connect over the MySQL Workbench, which doesn't work either.

Workbench error:

[image]

Comment: Hi! Can you write the command you're running for logging into the mysql client? Also, I'd recommend you to use a package like XAMPP (https://www.apachefriends.org), which comes with MySQL (or MariaDB) and runs out of the box when installed.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your Answer. I'm not using any Command to enter the Command Line. I maybe should have written that I'm using Windows Server 2016. I'm using the normal .exe file.

Comment: Can you post an screenshot of the MySQL Workbench error?

Comment: Sure, It's in the original post ("Workbench Error")

Comment: It seems that the MySQL server is not installed/configured properly. This is what I'd do:

- Open MySQL Installer and verify that "MySQL Server" appears in the list of installed software
- Run "services.msc" from Windows start menu and check that "MySQLXX" service is in the list and is "running"
- If some of the above conditions are not met, I would uninstall everything from MySQL, restart the PC and install it again, verifying that all the steps in the configuration are correct

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, I installed every again but in an older version and it works.